# How to return success for .save() even if record also exists? -- Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm trying to modify the following code to make it return the flash notice and success if the `email` exists.

```
class SubscribersController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json

  def create
    @subscriber = Subscriber.new(:first_name     => params[:first_name],
                                 :last_name      => params[:last_name],
                                 :email          => params[:email],
                                 :ip_address     => request.remote_ip,
                                 :referring_page => request.referer )
    if @subscriber.save
      flash[:notice] = "You've been subscribed!"
    end

    respond_with(@subscriber)
  end

end
```

**How could I check if the email address exists already and return success with the flash message?**

**I don't want to throw an error if the email already exists (which the model checks for) -- I want to still say you've been subscribed.**

I've tried checking with `.present?` but it throws an error:

```
<h1>
  NoMethodError
    in SubscribersController#create
</h1>
<pre>undefined method `model_name' for ActiveRecord::Relation:Class</pre>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe, you could use a dynamic finder for this matter.

```
@subscriber = Subscriber.find_or_initialize_by_email(params[:email], { :first_name => ..., })
```

however, I think, saving a persisted record will return `false`, so you need to check if

```
@subscriber.persisted? or @subscriber.save
  flash[:success] = "You've been subscribed!"
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Add a validation in de subscriber model

```
validates_uniqueness_of :email
```

and in the controller

```
@subscriber.valid?

if @subscriber.errors.on(:email) == "XXX"
   flash[:error] = "email address exists already"
end
```